# Invariant Violation - reactjs - basic example with native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So, I'm learning the basics of react native, following the documentation and I'm coding two components.

I created a components folder in my project, with a greetings.js file, and in this file I have to following code:

```
  import React,   { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text, View } from 'react-native';

class Greeting extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Text>
                Hello {this.props.name}!
            </Text>
        );
    }
}

export default class LotsOfGreetings extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <Greeting name="Rexar"/>
                <Greeting name="Jaina"/>
                <Greeting name="Valeera"/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Here is my App.js:

```
    import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, Image } from 'react-native';
import { Greetings, LotsOfGreetings } from './components/greetings';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {

    return (
      <LotsOfGreetings></LotsOfGreetings>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

I'm getingthis error:

> Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) ...

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Your exports are incorrect, change it to

```
export class Greeting extends Component
```

and

```
export class LotsOfGreetings extends Component
```

Comment: Please, explain to me, why the example uses the default ?

And I noticed that if I rename the file to the same name of the class, it works.. but when I have two classes in the same file, I get this error again...

Comment: And I'm sorry, if I keep both classes in the same file, just like you said, it doesn't work

Comment: Are you exporting both the classes in the file ? When you do a default export, you don't need to put them inside braces {} for imports.

Comment: Also, I see you are importing Greetings instead of Greeting, for default exports while importing you can use any alias but for other exports you need to be specific while importing.

Answer (score 0):

In `App.js` just change

From

```
import { Greetings, LotsOfGreetings } from './components/greetings';
```

To:

```
import LotsOfGreetings from './components/greetings';
```

This is the correct way to load as default.

You can check more details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)